# Hyperledger composer on multiple hosts

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, docker-swarm

I am following the tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org
for running fabric on multiple hosts.I am using two ubuntu VMs,everything seems to be working fine till the 18th step (trying to ping alice@trade-network)

I get the following error:

> Error: Error trying invoke business network with transaction id 613044c19d2d32bd1d4e990710a7bed14637c074b9967846ffb6458ece2eb744. Error: Peer localhost:8051 has rejected transaction '613044c19d2d32bd1d4e990710a7bed14637c074b9967846ffb6458ece2eb744' with code ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE
>   Command failed

My connection profile

```js
{
    "name": "byfn-network",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.example.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.org1.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer0.org2.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.org2.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        },
        "Org2": {
            "mspid": "Org2MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org2.example.com",
                "peer1.org2.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org2.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nP18ueegmAiAgEyI0zMB1AgSkoCDi8OOYl7bRWAwP+OKHtHWdz6VKHg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nC+8INOSOiU+BHhqxcow=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nC+8INOSOiU+BHhqxcow=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n0bhsg1aFVA0IXhcGLw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org2.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n0bhsg1aFVA0IXhcGLw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca-org1",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        },
        "ca.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:8054",
            "caName": "ca-org2",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already replaced the Localhost with my VMs ip address but i still get the same error

My endorsement policy

```js
{
    "identities": [
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "Org1MSP"
            }
        },
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "Org2MSP"
            }
        }
    ],
    "policy": {
        "2-of": [
            {
                "signed-by": 0
            },
            {
                "signed-by": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My docker logs for ca.org1

```html
2019/02/07 04:58:40 [INFO] Created default configuration file at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [INFO] Starting server in home directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [INFO] Server Version: 1.2.0-stable
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:1 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Making server filenames absolute
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initializing default CA in directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Init CA with home /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server and config {Version:1.2.0-stable Cfg:{Identities:{AllowRemove:false} Affiliations:{AllowRemove:false}} CA:{Name:ca-org1 Keyfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/99f226837128e4c62e87e98f15d8aa8af13e8bb5a44b06405ce38f58ca4b4aab_sk Certfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem Chainfile:ca-chain.pem} Signing:0xc420310e10 CSR:{CN:fabric-ca-server Names:[{C:US ST:North Carolina L: O:Hyperledger OU:Fabric SerialNumber:}] Hosts:[ff301f8af2e2 localhost] KeyRequest:<nil> CA:0xc42030fcc0 SerialNumber:} Registry:{MaxEnrollments:-1 Identities:[{ Name:**** Pass:**** Type:client Affiliation: MaxEnrollments:0 Attrs:map[hf.GenCRL:1 hf.Registrar.Attributes:* hf.AffiliationMgr:1 hf.Registrar.Roles:* hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles:* hf.Revoker:1 hf.IntermediateCA:1]  }]} Affiliations:map[org1:[department1 department2] org2:[department1]] LDAP:{ Enabled:false URL:ldap://****:****@<host>:<port>/<base> UserFilter:(uid=%s) GroupFilter:(memberUid=%s) Attribute:{[uid member] [{ }] map[groups:[{ }]]} TLS:{false [] { }}  } DB:{ Type:sqlite3 Datasource:fabric-ca-server.db TLS:{false [] { }}  } CSP:0xc420278cf0 Client:<nil> Intermediate:{ParentServer:{ URL: CAName:  } TLS:{Enabled:false CertFiles:[] Client:{KeyFile: CertFile:}} Enrollment:{ Name: Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile: Label: CSR:<nil> Type:x509  }} CRL:{Expiry:24h0m0s} Idemix:{IssuerPublicKeyfile: IssuerSecretKeyfile: RevocationPublicKeyfile: RevocationPrivateKeyfile: RHPoolSize:0 NonceExpiration: NonceSweepInterval:}}
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] CA Home Directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Checking configuration file version '1.2.0-stable' against server version: '1.2.0-stable'
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP: &{ProviderName:SW SwOpts:0xc420278d50 PluginOpts:<nil> Pkcs11Opts:<nil>}
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP with software options &{SecLevel:256 HashFamily:SHA2 Ephemeral:false FileKeystore:0xc4203104f0 DummyKeystore:<nil>}
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initialize key material
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Making CA filenames absolute
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [INFO] The CA key and certificate files already exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [INFO] Key file location: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/99f226837128e4c62e87e98f15d8aa8af13e8bb5a44b06405ce38f58ca4b4aab_sk
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [INFO] Certificate file location: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Validating the CA certificate and key
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Check CA certificate for valid dates
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Check CA certificate for valid usages
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Check CA certificate for valid IsCA value
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Check that key type is supported
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Check that key size is of appropriate length
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Check that public key and private key match
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Validation of CA certificate and key successful
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Loading CN from existing enrollment information
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initializing DB
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initializing 'sqlite3' database at '/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db'
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Using sqlite database, connect to database in home (/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db) directory
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating SQLite database (/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db) if it does not exist...
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating users table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating affiliations table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating certificates table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating credentials table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating revocation_authority_info table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating nonces table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating properties table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Successfully opened sqlite3 DB
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Checking database schema...
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Update SQLite schema, if using outdated schema
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Upgrade identities table
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating users table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Upgrade affiliation table
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating affiliations table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Upgrade certificates table
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Creating certificates table if it does not exist
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initializing identity registry
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initialized DB identity registry
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Get properties [identity.level affiliation.level certificate.level]
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Checking database levels 'map[affiliation.level:0 certificate.level:0 identity.level:0]' against server levels '&{Identity:1 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}'
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Loading identity table
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Loading identity 'admin'
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity admin
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Max enrollment value verification - User specified max enrollment: 0, CA max enrollment: -1
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Add identity admin
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Successfully added identity admin to the database
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Registered identity: { Name:**** Pass:**** Type:client Affiliation: MaxEnrollments:-1 Attrs:map[hf.Registrar.Attributes:* hf.AffiliationMgr:1 hf.Registrar.Roles:* hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles:* hf.Revoker:1 hf.IntermediateCA:1 hf.GenCRL:1]  }
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Successfully loaded identity table
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Loading affiliations table
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1' added
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1.department1
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1.department1' added
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1.department2
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1.department2' added
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org2
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org2' added
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org2.department1
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org2.department1' added
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Successfully loaded affiliations table
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Checking and performing migration, if needed
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Updating database level to &{Identity:1 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [INFO] Initialized sqlite3 database at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] Initializing enrollment signer
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] No key found in BCCSP keystore, attempting fallback
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] validating configuration
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] validate local profile
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] profile is valid
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] validate local profile
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] profile is valid
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] validate local profile
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] profile is valid
2019/02/07 04:58:41 [DEBUG] CA initialization successful
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [INFO] The issuer key was successfully stored. The public key is at: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/IssuerPublicKey, secret key is at: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore/IssuerSecretKey
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [INFO] The revocation key was successfully stored. The public key is at: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/IssuerRevocationPublicKey, private key is at: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore/IssuerRevocationPrivateKey
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [INFO] Home directory for default CA: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [DEBUG] 1 CA instance(s) running on server
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [DEBUG] TLS is enabled
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [DEBUG] TLS Certificate: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem, TLS Key: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/99f226837128e4c62e87e98f15d8aa8af13e8bb5a44b06405ce38f58ca4b4aab_sk
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [DEBUG] Client authentication type requested: noclientcert
2019/02/07 04:58:42 [INFO] Listening on https://0.0.0.0:7054
2019/02/07 05:13:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 05:28:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 05:43:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] Received request for /api/v1/enroll
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] ca.Config: &{Version:1.2.0-stable Cfg:{Identities:{AllowRemove:false} Affiliations:{AllowRemove:false}} CA:{Name:ca-org1 Keyfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/99f226837128e4c62e87e98f15d8aa8af13e8bb5a44b06405ce38f58ca4b4aab_sk Certfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem Chainfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-chain.pem} Signing:0xc420310e10 CSR:{CN:ca.org1.example.com Names:[{C:US ST:North Carolina L: O:Hyperledger OU:Fabric SerialNumber:}] Hosts:[ff301f8af2e2 localhost] KeyRequest:<nil> CA:0xc42030fcc0 SerialNumber:} Registry:{MaxEnrollments:-1 Identities:[{ Name:**** Pass:**** Type:client Affiliation: MaxEnrollments:0 Attrs:map[hf.Registrar.Roles:* hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles:* hf.Revoker:1 hf.IntermediateCA:1 hf.GenCRL:1 hf.Registrar.Attributes:* hf.AffiliationMgr:1]  }]} Affiliations:map[org1:[department1 department2] org2:[department1]] LDAP:{ Enabled:false URL:ldap://****:****@<host>:<port>/<base> UserFilter:(uid=%s) GroupFilter:(memberUid=%s) Attribute:{[uid member] [{ }] map[groups:[{ }]]} TLS:{false [] { }}  } DB:{ Type:sqlite3 Datasource:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db TLS:{false [] { }}  } CSP:0xc420278cf0 Client:<nil> Intermediate:{ParentServer:{ URL: CAName:  } TLS:{Enabled:false CertFiles:[] Client:{KeyFile: CertFile:}} Enrollment:{ Name: Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile: Label: CSR:<nil> Type:x509  }} CRL:{Expiry:24h0m0s} Idemix:{IssuerPublicKeyfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/IssuerPublicKey IssuerSecretKeyfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore/IssuerSecretKey RevocationPublicKeyfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/IssuerRevocationPublicKey RevocationPrivateKeyfile:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore/IssuerRevocationPrivateKey RHPoolSize:1000 NonceExpiration:15s NonceSweepInterval:15m}}
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity admin
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] DB: Login user admin with max enrollments of -1 and state of 0
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] DB: identity admin successfully logged in
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity admin
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] Processing sign request: id=admin, CommonName=admin, Subject=<nil>
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] Request is not for a CA signing certificate
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] Checking CSR fields to make sure that they do not exceed maximum character limits
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] Finished processing sign request
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity admin
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [INFO] signed certificate with serial number 535780223956516344199676533982675670139844127475
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] DB: Insert Certificate
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] Saved serial number as hex 5dd937565ba36de887e5f0d527338789a7776af3
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] saved certificate with serial number 535780223956516344199676533982675670139844127475
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [DEBUG] Successfully incremented state for identity admin to 1
2019/02/07 05:51:31 [INFO] 172.20.0.1:50314 POST /api/v1/enroll 201 0 "OK"
2019/02/07 05:58:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 06:13:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 06:28:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 06:43:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 06:58:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 07:13:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 07:28:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 07:43:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 07:58:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 08:10:57 http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50710: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2019/02/07 08:11:27 http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50714: EOF
2019/02/07 08:11:27 http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50718: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2019/02/07 08:12:27 http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50722: EOF
2019/02/07 08:12:27 http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50726: EOF
2019/02/07 08:12:27 http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50730: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2019/02/07 08:13:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 08:16:46 http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50734: EOF
2019/02/07 08:28:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 08:43:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 08:58:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 09:13:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 09:28:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 09:43:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 09:58:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 10:13:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
2019/02/07 10:28:42 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-org1'
```

container logs peer1.org1.example.com

```js
2019-02-07 13:16:18.317 UTC [lscc] executeDeployOrUpgrade -> ERRO 04c cannot get package for chaincode (trade-network:0.1.14)-err:open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/trade-network.0.1.14: no such file or directory
2019-02-07 13:16:18.317 UTC [endorser] **ProcessProposal -> ERRO 04d** [mychannel][26d4d83b] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid: 26d4d83bd30eb2bf950aa298410bea59fc99a2c03f25376375bbcf9bd827ba49
2019-02-07 13:17:14.637 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 04e Created state database mychannel_trade-network
2019-02-07 13:17:17.691 UTC [cceventmgmt] HandleStateUpdates -> INFO 04f Channel [mychannel]: Handling LSCC state update for chaincode [trade-network]
2019-02-07 13:17:17.944 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 050 Created CouchDB index [selectCommoditiesByExchange] in state database [mychannel_trade-network] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesByExchangeDoc]
2019-02-07 13:17:17.949 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 051 Created CouchDB index [selectCommoditiesByOwner] in state database [mychannel_trade-network] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesByOwnerDoc]
2019-02-07 13:17:17.964 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 052 Created CouchDB index [selectCommodities] in state database [mychannel_trade-network] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesDoc]
2019-02-07 13:17:17.972 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 053 Created CouchDB index [selectCommoditiesWithHighQuantity] in state database [mychannel_trade-network] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesWithHighQuantityDoc]
2019-02-07 13:17:18.002 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 054 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [5] with 1 transaction(s)
2019-02-07 13:20:22.563 UTC [vscc] Validate -> WARN 055 Endorsement policy failure for transaction txid=68d0f2e57a00cd857cbc8157824754f82bc38030efc2c80bf3a0dedaad83fa6f, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
2019-02-07 13:20:22.563 UTC **[committer/txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 056** VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = 68d0f2e57a00cd857cbc8157824754f82bc38030efc2c80bf3a0dedaad83fa6f returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
2019-02-07 13:20:22.585 UTC [valimpl] preprocessProtoBlock -> WARN 057 Channel [mychannel]: Block [6] Transaction index [0] TxId [68d0f2e57a00cd857cbc8157824754f82bc38030efc2c80bf3a0dedaad83fa6f] marked as invalid by committer. Reason code [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE]
2019-02-07 13:20:23.042 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 058 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [6] with 1 transaction(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your peer logs?. That seems composer are trying to communicate with your peer 1, so use:

> docker container logs peer1.org1.example.com

Maybe there is a problem with your identity

Comment: added the logs...i was able to recreate the error n im using fabric:1.2 composer:0.20

Comment: Okey, the problem here is that one of your org are not endorsing the transaction. You have 2-of (Org1,Org2), that mean Org1 and Org2 should endorse the transaction. Check peer0.org2 logs or peer1.org2 logs  to see why Org2 are not endorsing the transaction.

Comment: On vm2 for peer0.org1 and peer1org1 i have INFO 045 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [4] with 1 transaction(s)
                                                                                                                 
peer0.org2 and peer1.org2 i have  CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 051 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [4] with 1 transaction(s)
2019-02-07 13:10:17.060 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 052 Installed Chaincode [trade-network] Version [0.2.6-deploy.0] to peer

Comment: On Vm1 for peer1.org1 peer0.org2 and peer1.org2 i have the same error            validateTx -> ERRO 056 VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = 68d0f2e57a00cd857cbc8157824754f82bc38030efc2c80bf3a0dedaad83fa6f returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
for peer0.org1 i get             ERRO 027 Failed verifying signature from 172.19.0.5:7051 : Could not acquire policy manager for channel mychannel